# cordova create commnd error [create,js(54, 5)]

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I tried to create a new androind projet with cordova in windows 7 64-bit but I encountered this error

```
P:\cordova-2.9.1\cordova-android\bin>create M:\androidprojects\ net.nasirtech.he
lloworld helloworld
Creating new android project...
Building jar and js files...
Copying template files...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Creating appinfo.jar...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
P:\cordova-2.9.1\cordova-android\bin\create.js(54, 5) Microsoft JScript runtime
error: Path not found
```

I've installed java, ADT, android sdk, ant & everything I needed. and also added them to PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

address in **create** command should not end with "\"

The address should be

```
M:\androidprojects
```

no "\" at the end